# API request different in dev mode than in prod mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, cross-domain

I have a vue.js cli client which consumes an API which resides on Azure (I have developped both client and API).
When I run the client in development mode (npm run serve) my API is correctly responding with Status Code 200. However, when I build the production version (npm run build) and run the dist version locally (serve -s dist), my API call is rejected (400 bad request).

It seems that the build process is doing compiling something differently.

My ApiService.js code snippet:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const apiURL = 'https://my-api.azurewebsites.net/' 

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiURL,
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})

userLogin(credentials) {
    return apiClient.post('/login', credentials)
}
```

[This is the diff of the two API calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58noa.png)

When I call the API in production mode the browser reports a cors issue:

> `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-api.azurewebsites.net/login' from origin 'http://www.mysite.ch' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I spent many ours on the web to find a solution, but I was not successful. Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: seems like something to do with route you had with `/login` with ERROR code 400, are you using vue SPA + vue-router history mode without any-prerender/SSR after build for production? Another workaround is redirect rule in Azure site.

Comment: Use Postman to test the API calls. At present you are trying to test both ends at once, which is always problematic as it makes it very hard to isolate issues to one end or the other. A server can return HTTP 400 for a variety of reasons, such as a feature not being enabled or data being in the wrong format. If you can get your API calls working with Postman, you will then be in a better place to try your client app.

Comment: Hi @SCKim, yes, it's a vue SPA and the router is set to history mode. I will look into your hints regarding prerender/SSR and redirect in Azure. Thanks.

Comment: @RegEdit, the API works using Postman and also if I run it in on http://localhost:8080 with npm run serve. It's not running when I build the dist file and run this (serve -s dist). So, I assume that the root cause in on the client side. The screenshot with the diff 
(attached above) indicates that the client is sending the API calls differently.

Comment: @Phil, it's `vue-cli-service serve`. I am not very experienced with the whole deployment process. It could be a basic issue, but unknown to me ;-)

Comment: I have added the CORS console error to the description which I get when I run it off the built version.

Comment: I can't see the `-s` option in [the docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-serve). Are you sure that's what you're using? If I had to guess, Id say you're using [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) as documented [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#previewing-locally)

Comment: Again, what do your server logs say about the 400 response status? What does your server-side CORS configuration look like? Perhaps you've only allowed requests from `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: @Phil, your absolutely right, I am using it as described in the second case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is working locally because your local domain is passing the CORS request. Ultimately this is just a CORS configuration issue. Your production domain has not been whitelisted. I'm not sure what your back-end is or how Azure affects it, but you need to whitelist your production domain for API consumption.

This is an example of setting a CORS policy in Express: https://flaviocopes.com/express-cors/

Just make sure you don't allow ALL origins as that is a security risk.

Comment: Thanks for all contributors. I have added the URL of my client to the whitelist on the server. Since then it seems to work. 
However, what is strange is that I had a * before, which should include my client URL, too. So, I am not 100% sure what the root cause was at the end. The * is now removed.
Anyway, your support was very helpful.